# Adding/removing items dynamically from JSON data parse from mySQL Database with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object-literal

I have a mysql database with column ID, NAME , TYPE.
The database is then parsed in JSON structure as follows

```
[
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
    {id: "2", name: "Witches of Eastwick", type: "comedy"},
    {id: "3", name: "X-Men", type: "action"},
    {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People", type: "drama"},
    {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"},
    {id: "6", name: "Toy Story", type: "children"}
]
```

If I want to add/remove item from the client side. How should I update it ?
I know I can use setInterval or setTimeout to refresh the table, but using this method will repopulate the table with the updated JSON object from the database.

Is there better ways to do it dynamically, with only the modified item getting updated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways

**1) Processing at client end.**

Assume you keep the data in one variable as follows

var data = {your JSON} //Keep this variable only to identify the delta changes.

And when you submit your changes to the server just send only the delta changes.

```
var deltachanges = {
 "added" = [
            {id: "7", name: "Snatch V2", type: "crime"},
            {id: "8", name: "Witches of Eastwick V2", type: "comedy"}],
  "updated" =  [
                 {id: "3", name: "X-Men - V3", type: "action"},
                 {id: "4", name: "Ordinary People -V4", type: "drama"}],
 "deleted" =  [
                 {id: "5", name: "Billy Elliot", type: "drama"}]
}
```

Now in your service just process this request with the above delta data and populate your data accordingly.

**2) Processing at server side**
Similar to client end processing, at the server side the delta changes has to be calculated, before it's persisted to database.